# How to query object with node.js in parse server

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to use node to request data from my Parse server. The documentation from Parse doesn't make sense to me at all. Can someone please complete my code so I can request all objects in a class named "Items"?

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = 'mongodb://xx';

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost!');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xx',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'xx', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://site.herokuapp.com/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('lol');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

This is all the [documentation](http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/) Parse provides but it doesn't work for me. I tried [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cloud-express) too but still no result. Can someone please edit my code so that I can work with cloud code? Ultimately, I want to call the function "hello" in my browser and view all the objects for class "Items".

Comment: "Complete my code" questions don't really fly too well around here.  You should try to reduce your problem to its smallest, reproducible version.  Think specific questions, not broad requests.

Comment: Is your server running successfully? What error are you seeing in the logs? Does the main.js actually exist in that directory? Can you give us more to work with please.

Comment: Thanks @SnakeBlisken the problem is now solved. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured out the answer. By now, many of you have hopefully migrated your Parse server to something like Heroku as they are shutting down in almost a month. For those of you that face the same challenge in the future and have migrated to Heroku, remember that your data is being stored on mlab in json format. If you want to save, view or update your data and you want to access those data over http or https using node, you would have to use mongodb's API (NOT THE PARSE SERVER API) and include it in your packages.json. Look at mlab's [documentation](http://docs.mlab.com/languages/) instead of connecting your Parse Cloud Code to node.js. Unfortunately Parse hasn't provided enough documentation to show how to use node with their API properly so stick with mlab's API instead.